# How to add a underlying progressbar across two or more ListViewItem in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image]

Suppose I have a 2 by 2 listview. I want to

```
|  AAA | BBB  |
|  CCC | DDD  |
^ ProgressBar ^
```

have a progressbar spans over the whole second row, which means the left side of CCC is 0 and the right side of DDD is 100.

In addition, make the bar lies between the text (CCC, DDD) and the listviewitem's background.

Can I define it as a style? Or can I do it in code?

Edit:
In QT I custom draw the background of the listview to make it look like a progress bar behind the text. If I can do the similar thing, it will be fine to me.

Comment: if you can draw it in QT and capture a screenshot showing what you want to achieve, then the question is easier to understand, which is better than ASCII arts.

Comment: Yes I should have.. I uploaded a pic of what I did in qt. Each row is actually a 2 by 2 qtableview. I use QStyledItemDelegate to achieve this effect but I have to port it to wpf...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but you may need to change your item `ViewModel` class structure.

You need to specify a custom `ItemTemplate` for the `ListView` where you would define the controls for displaying `CCC` and `DDD` values and the extra value which is displayed via the `ProgressBar`.

**NB:** Automatic properties used for interface definition brevity - they would normally be fully `INotifyPropertyChanged` enabled.

```
public class ItemVM : ViewModel
{
    public string CCC {get;set;}
    public string DDD {get;set;}
    public int ProgressBarValue {get;set;}
}
```

and the the XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition/>
                 <ColumnDefinition/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.ZIndex="1" Content="{Binding CCC}"/>
              <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.ZIndex="1" Content="{Binding DDD}"/>
              <ProgressBar Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.ZIndex="0" Value="{Binding ProgressBarValue}"/>
            </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**NB:**`Items` is of type `ObservableCollection<ItemVM>` and is assumed to be in scope of the containing `Control`/`UserControl` `DataContext`. `ZIndex` is used to control which controls are on top of the other.

Comment: just place the progress bar before the labels, then it is showing beneath the labels, you do not need to use the ZIndex property.

Comment: True, but I prefer to be deterministic about the placement.

Comment: I believe this will work but I'm trying to check why I cannot see the progress bar... I'm trying to comment out some of my other styles

Comment: now it works! I need to set textbox's background to null

Comment: If you don't need input from the user, rather use a `Label`. A `TextBox` is primarily for taking input, whereas a `Label` is pure display.